# Manifold and Weak Topologies Coincide

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold and $X_i$ a topological space with $f_i: M \rightarrow X_i$ for each $i \in I$. The weak topology on $M$ induced by $\{f_i\}$ is the coarsest topology on $M$ for which $f_i$ is continuous for each $i \in I$. The collection of sets of the form $f_i^{-1}[U_i]$ for $U_i$ open in $X_i$ for all $i \in I$ is a subbase for the weak topology on $M$. If the manifold topology on $M$ coincides with the weak topology on $M$, is this subbase also a base?

Comment: Welcome! Could you specify what you mean by "manifold topology"?

Comment: Thanks! Let $M$ be a set. An $n$-chart on $M$ is a pair $(U, \varphi)$ where $U \subseteq M$ and $\varphi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is injective and such that $\varphi[U]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. One defines compatibility of $n$-charts in the natural way. An $n$-dimensional manifold is a pair $(M, C)$ where $M$ is a set and $C$ is a maximal collection of compatible $n$-charts covering $M$. A set $S \subseteq M$ is open in the manifold topology if, for all $p \in M$, there is an $n$-chart $(U, \varphi)$ such that $p \in U$ and $U \subseteq S$.